# How to import multiple files at once using UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Tags: uikit

Is it possible to use UIDocumentPickerViewController to allow the user to select multiple files for import from another application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code snippet, this will add "Select" button beside the title, to select multiple files at once and import it.

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *dvc = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc]initWithDocumentTypes:arrContents inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
        dvc.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:dvc animated:true completion:^{
            if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
                    dvc.allowsMultipleSelection = true;
            }
        }];
```

and

`- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentsAtURLs:(NSArray <NSURL *>*)urls`

to get the list of selected files.

Answer (score -1):

UIDocumentPickerViewController delegate can return only 1 file, not all:

```
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url
```

So, unfortunately, it's not possible :(